# c# Get Location of programmatically added Button on Click

Tags: c#, forms, button, location

I am creating a lot of buttons on different locations dynamically and each of them should respond to the same event. Since I must know which button I clicked I need the location of the button I clicked. I cannot add a different EventHandler for every button, they spawn on a grid 30*50, meaning in the worst case I get 1500 buttons. That's a lot of buttons.

```
    private void createNewEnt(int ID, Point position, int style)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Location = getItemGridLoc(position);
        b.Text = getInitial(ID);
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 21);
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(bClick);
        if (style == 0)
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.White;
            b.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else if (style == 1)
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.Black;
            b.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        b.BringToFront();
    }

    void bClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you clicked on a Button :D");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sender` argument of the event handler and cast it to a button and then retrieve its location.

```
void bClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button cb = (sender as Button);
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked on a Button :D!");
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Location of clicked Button : {0}, {1}.", cb.Location.X, cb.Location.Y)); // This is just for example.
}
```

Similarly, you can also do other stuff with the Button, i.e, `cb` and/or get its other properties.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Location of clicked Button : {0}, {1}.", cb.Location.X, cb.Location.Y)); SO wont let me edit.. thanks for the answer works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
void bClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn1 = (Button)sender;
    string buttonID = btn1.ID;
    MessageBox.Show("you clicked on a Button :D");
}
```

This is how you can take the button ID and every other property needed.